# Not able to pass JSON object as second argument in javascript function call

Tags: javascript, json

I am generating rows in javascript with for each loop, where each row has an anchor and with onclick of that anchor I am trying to pass a JSON object as  second argument in my javascript function but I am getting undefined error.

I have already verified that result is a JSON object
Here is my code to generate rows.

```
 _.each(
response.details,
function(result, key, list) {searchdetails += "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\" ><a class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"button\" onClick='Updatedetails(\"2\",result)'>Details</a></td></tr>";
   });
```

I am getting below error:-
[image]

I have also tried by appending it like string as below:-

```
 _.each(
response.details,
function(result, key, list) {searchdetails += "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\" ><a class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"button\" onClick='Updatedetails(\"2\","+result+")'>Details</a></td></tr>";
   });
```

With this, I am getting below error:-
[image]

Can anybody tell me how do I pass it as JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes and need to stringify your object:

```
function(result, key, list) {searchdetails += "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\" ><a class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"button\" onClick='Updatedetails(\"2\",\""+JSON.stringify(result)+"\")'>Details</a></td></tr>";
```

Note how modified code differs:

```
"...'Updatedetails(\"2\",\""+JSON.stringify(result)+"\")'..."
```

Comment: Updatedetails further iterates over this result object. So I cant pass this as string. it has to be JSON object.  I know I can convert it back to JSON in Updatedetails but I cant change anything in Updatedetails object.

Comment: In that case, the only solution I can think of is to define result as a global: `window.result = result` and then apply your first attempt

Comment: Thanks for replying. That's the last option in my mind. Is it something recently updated that is causing this issue? My code was working fine couple of weeks back.

Comment: I don't know of any updates that would cause this issue. It must be some change in your code or something.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I could not find any other solution. Have to make it global.